# Binary translation zero issue

Tags: binary

i'm  a student and for this semester i have to deal with binary translation. I use multiple online [tools](https://binarytotext.net) for such conversion. My question is,

The binary to text conversion for "A" is: 01000001

but as per the book "1000001" is correct answer for "A".

However, the online binary translator returns nothing when I insert "1000001".

So my question is, which is the correct answer for binary to text?

Comment: There are many ways to encode text into binary.  ASCII has both seven and eight bit versions, for example.  There is no one correct answer.  This is not a mathematical problem, either.

Comment: [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters). But this question belongs on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC No, it would be closed as off-topic on Stack Overflow because it's not a question asking about a programming problem. It *might* be ok on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encoding-scheme+binary).

Comment: *The binary to text conversion for "A" is: 01000001* You have that backwards. "A" is text, 01000001 is binary. So that's a text to binary conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both answers are correct. Adding zeros on the left side of a number does not change the number. For example, the numbers "0100" and "100" are same.

As long as I know binary numbers are eight-bit numbers. So, actual conversion of "A" is "1000001" but with a view to make this number an eight-bit number, they add extra required zero. On which tools u used?

Comment: There are many, I found on google. But now I read binary translation on wiki and everything seems clear.